# Why `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.onload` throws Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

```js
try {
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.onload
} catch(e) {
  document.write(e)
}
```

I am trying to write a wrapper on XMLHttpRequest constructor, while this error throws. What is the reason?